# How can I add an input number to an image?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I would like to have a script that inputs a number and an image and then it writes the number in a corner of the image.

Then I would generalise this script to lists of both inputs.

However, I have no idea if there are specific languages / applications to do this kind of image processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend ImageMagick, which is free and installed on most Linux distros and readily installed on Windows and Mac OSX. It is downloadable from - [here](http://imagemagick.org). You can use it at the command line or from PHP/Perl/Ruby and most other languages.

At the command line you can do this:

```
convert input.jpg -gravity southeast \
          -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 'Dail Beagh' \
          -stroke  none   -fill white    -annotate 0 'Dail Beagh' \
          output.jpg
```

[image]

Or this...

```
convert input.jpg -fill red -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity SouthWest \
        -annotate +0+5 'Dail Beagh' output2.jpg
```

[image]

Or any number of other versions - [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#anno_on)

If you want to script it, you would save the following in a file called `title`

```
#!/bin/bash
image=$1
title=$2

convert "$image" -gravity southeast \
          -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 "$title" \
          -stroke  none   -fill white    -annotate 0 "$title" \
          output.jpg

convert "$image" -fill red -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity SouthWest \
        -annotate +0+5 "$title" output2.jpg
```

and then make it executable with

```
chmod +x title
```

and then run it with

```
./title "input.jpg" "some funky title"
```

or if you specifically want a number

```
./title "some image somewhere.png" 56
```

[image]

Or, supposing you have some ready-made digits saved as `GIF` files, e.g.

**0.gif**

[image]

and **9.gif**

[image]

You could append them side-by-side to make a label like this:

```
convert 9.gif 9.gif 0.gif +append label.gif
```

to make this:

[image]

and then overlay it onto your image with

```
convert input.jpg -gravity southeast label.gif -composite output.jpg
```

[image]

Or, you can do that all in one go with this:

```
convert input.jpg -gravity southeast   \
    \( 9.gif 9.gif 0.gif +append \)    \
    -composite output.jpg
```

Comment: I am amazed how some bash commands can create such things! I am favoriting this to come back one day and do some test :) Well done Mark!!

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you. Yes, it constantly amazes me how powerful Imagemagick is too - TIFF, PNG, JPEG, edge-detection, colour correction, FFT, connected component analysis, animation, PDF, filtration, cropping, framing, overlaying, alpha compositing.... :-)